# What is a "backing pod"?

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

I'm going through the OpenShift-documentation right now and I stumbled over the word "backing pod".

The google-search for "backing pod" has exactly four entries and all of them refer to the same line of text.

Is this just a *backup* pod? Or is it a copied pod for redundancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely meant to be "the pod that is running your app / code / database".  "Backing" is used in the context of a backer - someone (the pod) providing support for a task (the service).

It should probably just say "the pods that are part of the service".